# rPi OS upgrade introduced Predictable Network Interface Names; can't get eth0 back and dhcp working again

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, dhcp

```
System:    Host: rpi32 Kernel: 5.15.56-v7+ armv7l bits: 32 Console: tty 0 Distro: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
Machine:   Type: ARM Device System: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 details: BCM2835 rev: a22082 serial: 000000009a5073f1
```

I had a working machine before the upgrade, ntp, dhcp (is actually isc-dhcpserver), dns all working.
Then upgraded the OS (to Bullseye) and could no longer connect to the rPi.

`dmesg` revealed that `eth0` could not be connected to.
The interface was identified as `enxb827eb5073f1`. en = Ethernet plus MAC address.

Some research revealed that what I am seeing is called "Predictable Network Interface Names".

It said this is the new standard/approach, due to multi-interface machines not necessarily assigning the interface name at kernel boot; e.g., it could be `eth0` on one boot, and `eth1` during another; not good for firewalls, etc.

So I changed the following config files to get dhcp working:

```
/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

... and changed `eth0` to `enxb827eb5073f1`.

No luck.

```
sudo service dhcpcd status
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
             └─wait.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-19 15:04:18 AEST; 28min ago
    Process: 859 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=6)
        CPU: 11ms

Aug 19 15:04:18 rpi32 systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Aug 19 15:04:18 rpi32 dhcpcd[859]: Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
Aug 19 15:04:18 rpi32 dhcpcd[859]: defines some interfaces that will use a
Aug 19 15:04:18 rpi32 dhcpcd[859]: DHCP client or static address
Aug 19 15:04:18 rpi32 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=6/NOTCONFIGURED
Aug 19 15:04:18 rpi32 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 19 15:04:18 rpi32 systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
```

and

```
dhcpd -t /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf: interface name too long (is 20)
```

Researching this topic pointed to incorrect `dhcpd` config, pointing to `udev` rules, and I do not understand, and from what I could see, did not contain interface reference.

---

I read here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/ that this naming scheme can be reverted by adding this: `net.ifnames=0` to the kernel command line (`/boot/cmdline.txt`).

This is what I did. I reverted all changes in the three config files listed above, plus in the `cmdline.txt`.

(I rebooted as required after these changes.)

and `dhcpd -t /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` still returns:

```
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf: interface name too long (is 20)
```

All services work, except `dhcp` (`ntp` is back up as well, as no changes where made here WRT `eth0` changes).

Now I wonder what else I need to do to get dhcp working again.

---

Config files:

```
ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether b8:27:eb:50:73:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14682  bytes 1148952 (1.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3460  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7079  bytes 1063400 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 105  bytes 10173 (9.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 105  bytes 10173 (9.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
cat /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server 
# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
#DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
#INTERFACESv4="enxb827eb5073f1"
INTERFACESv4="eth0"
#INTERFACESv6=""
```

```
cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private
```

```
cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
# 190803-1530 installed DHCP server on rPi32
#
# 170611-1933 MaxG: changed from none to interim
#ddns-update-style none;
ddns-update-style interim;

# 170612-2300 MaxG: added based on
# https://blog.bigdinosaur.org/running-bind9-and-isc-dhcp/
ddns-updates on;
update-static-leases on;

ddns-domainname "argylecourt.lan";
ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";

authoritative;

# 190804-1424 MaxG: added key and 2 zones
key DHCP_UPDATER {
    algorithm HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT;

    # Important: Replace this key with your generated key.
    # Also note that the key should be surrounded by quotes.
    secret "someKeyBlah";
};

zone argylecourt.lan. {
    primary 127.0.0.1;
    key DHCP_UPDATER;
}

zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
    primary 127.0.0.1;
    key DHCP_UPDATER;
}


# 150301 MaxG - added to shut up Windows PC from clogging
# syslog with DHCPACK and DHCPINFORM msgs (WPAD)
option wpad-url code 252 = text;


# my subnet specifications
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    #interface enxb827eb5073f1;
    # pool range; can have multiple ranges in this file
    range               192.168.1.50 192.168.1.199;
    option subnet-mask      255.255.255.0;
    option routers          192.168.1.1;

    ddns-domainname         "argylecourt.lan";
    ddns-rev-domainname     "in-addr.arpa";
    option broadcast-address    192.168.1.255;
    option domain-name      "argylecourt.lan";
    option domain-name-servers  192.168.1.8;
    option ntp-servers      192.168.1.8;    # Default NTP server to be used by DHCP clients
    default-lease-time      86400;      # 1 day
    max-lease-time          604800;     # 7 days
    option wpad-url "\n";
}

# reservations; must NOT be in pool
# sorted by assinged IP address

host maxg-x570 {
    # MaxG's PC -- x570
    # added 20220409-2106
    hardware ethernet 04:42:1a:95:2b:37;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.13;
}

host brother-mfc {
    # Brother Network Printer -- BRN_368926
    hardware ethernet 00:80:77:36:89:26;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.33;
    ddns-hostname "brothermfc8820d";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation and was not able to tell where the mistake was.

try $ **dhcpd /etc/dhcp/**

this will search the whole file and will point directly where the mistake is

Answer (score 0):

Well, well... how embarrassing!

The solution is simple:

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
```

Start the correct service. It is not `dhcp`, it is `isc-dhcp-server`!

What I do not understand is why this service was no longer auto-starting.
Anyway, problem, or rather stupidity solved.